# Elementary 6.1 will not allow dual boot, wipes entire disk

Tags: dual-boot, microsoft-windows, release-jolnir

I've tried on three different machines but every time Elementary doesn't give the option to install alongside windows. When I try to install windows after installing Elementary windows doesn't recognize the disk format and terminates. Any thoughts?

Comment: Same problem. Quite frustrating. Only distro I have paid for before I try it and the only one that will not dual boot.. trying to use 6.1 :-/